# MySQL - add text prefix before column name in SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, prefix

Here is my table:

```
| ID | NUMBER |
| 1  |  523   |
| 2  |  293   |
| 3  |  948   |
```

And now, I want to get all `NUMBER` values but I want to add in result two numbers - `48` - (without upadting existing results). So finally I want print these results:

```
| NUMBER   |
|  48523   |
|  48293   |
|  48948   |
```

So I need a query, something like this:

```
SELECT '48' + `number` FROM `table`
```

but this query doesn't work fine (this query only update column name from `NUMBER` to `48 + NUMBER`). 
Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `SELECT CONACT('48', number) AS number from table;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

```
SELECT CONCAT('48' , `number`) AS number FROM table
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/30db18/3)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT '48'+`number` NUMBER FROM `table`
```